# Instance of Show list for a custom datatype

Tags: string, list, haskell, instance

I have defined a (Matrix) datatype, as a 2D list:

```
newtype Matrix a = M [[a]]
```

and an instance for `Show`, as follows:

```
instance Show a => Show (Matrix a) where
    show (M a) = intercalate "\n" (map (unwords . map show) a) ++ "\n"
```

Which behaves like so:

```
> mat = M [[3,1,8],[6,3,0],[6,8,8]]
> mat
3 1 8
6 3 0
6 8 8
```

However, I'd like to handle how it prints lists, because the default behaviour looks a bit weird. How do I specify this? I've tried something like these:

```
instance Show a => Show ([Matrix a]) where
    show mat = case mat of
      [M a] -> intercalate "\n" (map (unwords . map show) a) ++ "\n"
      (m:ms) -> show m ++ "\n" ++ show ms

  instance Show a => Show (Matrix a) where
    show (M a)  = intercalate "\n" (map (unwords . map show) a) ++ "\n"
    show (m:ms) = show m ++ "\n" ++ show ms
```

But I just get syntax errors. I tried googling the issue, but I couldn't find anything (Perhaps I used the wrong keywords?)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Desired input and output:

```
mat1 = M [[1,2],[3,4]]
mat2 = M [[1,2],[3,4]]
> [mat1, mat2]
1 2
3 4,
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: You showed the input and output that you already have working. Could you add an example input and the desired output that you're having trouble with?

Comment: That'd probably be helpful! Edited.

Comment: I'm unsure about whether this is a good idea. `Show` is conventionally meant to produce single-line data representations, usually employing Haskell syntax for that. Using a multiple-line text like that will play weirdly with all standard containers like arrays, maps, sets, etc. (Lists `[]` are exceptional and can be customized, anyway.) I'd consider using a custom pretty-printing routine `representatrix` which lies outside the `Show` class.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the [`showList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showList) method is for:

```
instance Show a => Show (Matrix a) where
    show (M a) = intercalate "\n" (map (unwords . map show) a) ++ "\n"
    showList (m:ms) = shows m . ("\n" ++) . showList ms
```

Note that this doesn't handle empty lists, though, so you also need

```
    showList [] = id
```

(or whatever you want it to show for empty lists.)